# Mathjax stops rendering after clicking "An edit has been made to this post"

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax, editing

I have noticed in the last two weeks or so that after clicking the "An edit has been made ..." banner, the mathjax is not rendered.

Example (before):
[image: before image]

(and after):
[image: after image]

Refreshing the page renders the mathjax again.
Is this a (new) feature? And if not can something be done?

I am using Firefox 68.0.2 on Windows 7.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing on Chrome Version 76.0.3809.100, Windows 10.

Comment: Add me too in the list!

Comment: Happens on Firefox 68.0.2 on Unix, and on Windows 10. I just re-load.

Comment: My experience is that the MathJax eventually renders again, but it takes a long time (maybe 30 seconds).

Comment: Sometimes happens on Chrome. Indeed it renders again but it doesn't last too much. At most 2-3 seconds.

Comment: nevermind.  I have just seen an edited question and the mathjax is not rendered unless refreshing the page. It's the first time this happens, time ago it was 2-3 seconds and sometimes.

Comment: Same problem with Opera 62.0.3331.119 for Mac.  Reloading causes the MathJax to render.  It has been this way for a couple of days now.

Comment: Migh be related to [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30016/242) where  MathJax slowed down after questions were closed (this is still not completely fixed, see my comments there).

Comment: @EricWofsey Using FireFox version $68.0.1$ on Windows $7$, I noticed very similar behavior, i.e., it takes quite a while (about $30$ or so seconds as you mention) for MathJax to render on its own. However, refreshing the screen seems to always cause it to render again considerably faster.

Comment: Using Chrome 76.0.3809.100, I found that the problem has now disappeared. Anyone else experience the same thing?

Comment: Using Chrome Version 76.0.3809.132 and I still have the problem.

Comment: (1) It is perhaps worth noting that this is still an issue (see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30827/)). (2) As a workaround, the [MathJax bookmarklet](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/mathjax.html) can be used without forcing a reload.

Comment: Same problem here, with Safari on a Mac.

Comment: Same problem using Chromium 77.0.3865.90 on Linux (Fedora 30), dating back to slightly before the current post (persisting through both browser and OS updates).

Comment: This needs to be fixed! There's no reason, at least as a work-around, that clicking the "An edit has been made to this post" link shouldn't auto-refresh the webpage.

Comment: @Catija Any progress on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been fixed.

I'm embarrassed to say this was originally my fault.  I had refactored post reloading to fix a handful of small bugs in support of moderator tooling, and accidentally dropped the call to `styleCode()` that kicks off the MathJax rendering.

If you're familiar with browser debugging tools and want to verify for yourself that this is fixed without waiting for a question to get edited, you can run the following JavaScript to force a question to update:

```
StackExchange.realtime.reloadPosts([$('.question').data('questionid')])
```

Comment: I have no idea what a "browser's console" is, much less how to "trigger" something in it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry about that, I've updated my answer.  It was just some added context on a way to simulate a reload for users who have web development experience.  The problem should be fixed and you don't need to take any actions.

Comment: Great. This was really annoying.

Comment: This is not fixed on the unanswered questions page. When there are new questions and you click to expand them, the MathJax doesn't render.

Comment: I still see this problem on the active questions page as well. I can use the "render MathJax" bookmarklet to render, or reload the whole page.