# MathJax does not render when question is edited

Tags: bug, mathjax, editing

On my Chrome browser in Windows 10, whenever a question that has MathJax is edited the MathJax no longer renders and is shown as, for example, `$q$` instead of $q$. This seems to persist until I refresh the page. I'm sure this is not intended behavior, but it also seems that I can't possibly be the only one to see this so I would find it hard to believe that it isn't a known issue.

Last time I used my desktop computer to go on MSE was over a month ago, and I don't think this issue was present then.

I'm using Chrome version 77.0.3865.120. LeBlanc was kind enough to give a link to the same issue [Mathjax stops rendering after clicking "An edit has been made to this post"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30568/515527). The only thing that's different is the browser.

Comment: To be honest, while it's obviously not a solution to the problem, I just refresh the page whenever I see an edit or new answer or something. Faster than waiting

Comment: The Comments on the earlier Question reflect that the problem appears with multiple browsers and multiple operating systems.

Comment: and even affects mobile at last check. been on and off for a while.