# MathJax bugs out after edit

Tags: bug, mathjax

While I was reading an answer, the poster decided to edit it. I clicked on the button to refresh the question, but afterwards, MathJax didn't update. I had to refresh the page in order to see the equations again.[image]
I've had this happen before, so it's definitely some sort of bug.

Comment: Some similar posts: [MathJax does not render when question is edited](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30827) and [Mathjax stops rendering after clicking “An edit has been made to this post”](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30568).

Comment: You have the reload the page. It's super frustrating but what can you do. It's really annoying when editing tags.