# Mathjax renders really slowly

Tags: bug, mathjax

Mathjax often renders very slowly for me in the preview when I type up a question. I always have to stop typing and wait for 5 seconds. A similar complaint can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30016/mathjax-very-slow-in-questions-that-are-closed?rq=1). The answer there says that the issue is fixed, but it isn't for me. I have made a [screen recording](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/w5zi189z5v2d6bj/AAAgdW4iLjmnU8lzJMniGsz6a?dl=0) of the issue. I tried using a different browser, but that did not help. It doesn't happen every time.

**Edit.** I should mention that I only have the problem when I write my own question. When I answer the question of another person then the formulas render immediatelly in the preview, so I do not think that it is a problem with my computer.

Comment: Have you tried different MathJax renderers? See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30859/42969

Comment: Also: try it while no other programs are running on your computer, to see whether the delay is due to some other program in the background.

Comment: I have tried both things and it makes no difference :/

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35508/can-no-longer-quickly-preview-latex-on-mse